# Durable function stuck in running state

Tags: azure-durable-functions

I have a durable function which get stuck in "Running" status when an activity function fails. No activity function is running, why would that be the case? Last update date for this instance in functionInstances table is 2020-11-19T05:00:32.761Z

[image]

Comment: Please file an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues. Our team can look at the internal telemetry for your application to help diagnose the issue. It is incredibly unlikely any community members would be able to help diagnose this issue without that telemetry.

Comment: In general, my first recommendation would be to make sure you are using the latest version of the extension, and if you are using JavaScript or Python, using the latest version of their respective SDKs.

Comment: I checked the logs and found that application is continuously throwing outofmemoryexception. Fixed that problem and now application is working fine.

Comment: Glad to hear you were able to resolve the problem! OutOfMemory exceptions can be quite the problem for Durable Functions due to how the technology works behind the scenes with event sourcing. Keeping inputs/outputs small and passing references to larger pieces of data helps with this substantially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the logs in application insights and found that application is continuously throwing outofmemoryexception. Fixed that problem and now application is working fine.

Answer (score 2):

I have found an excellent tool to use to debug and trace Durable func apps: https://github.com/microsoft/DurableFunctionsMonitor

It proved very difficult to see what's happening within the hub/control queues/instances and history tables - this tool helps a lot with visualizing that. I'm running it as a VS Code extension:)